# Javascript string replace removes all double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js

The title says it all. I want to insert HTML strings into a file. `finalHTML` looks perfectly fine, while `master` does not contain any double quotes after the first line of `finalHTML`.

```
console.log(finalHTML); //this contains double quotes
master = master.toString('utf8').replace(/<svg.*?>.*<\/svg>/im, finalHTML);
console.log(master); //this does not.
```

Comment: what does `finalHtml` look like?  What does `master` look like before the replace?  Can you a make fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Actually, it was the replacement regex. It wasn't updating the file after the first time I generated it. Fixed that, it's fine now.